# Parse line of delimited text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, text, extract

Hi I'm quite new to javascript and I want to get extract a text but only a part of it. For example if it extracts this text:

```
honey_00.jpg :: 1200 x 1703 :: 369.39 KB
```

I want it to give me `honey_00.jpg` I don't want the other junk information. I only just want the file name. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var filename = str.match(/.+\.jpg/);
```

Note that this will only work if the filename is at the beginning of the string and you're fetching a .jpg file.

---

To match a .jpg, .png, or .gif file, you can use this:

```
var filename = str.match(/.+\.(jpg|png|gif)/)[0];
```

Comment: I like your method but the filename is going to be either jpg,png or gif. Is it possible to include all 3?

Answer (score 1):

You may use split function:

```
var str="honey_00.jpg :: 1200 x 1703 :: 369.39 K";
var n=str.split(" :: ");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g9b3D/1/

using Regex is an option, but as much as i know regex is slower.

**EDIT:** Maybe you'd like to see this one: http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-split/2

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression. For instance...

```
var text = "honey_00.jpg :: 1200 x 1703 :: 369.39 KB";
var pattern = /(.*) :: .* :: .*/;
var fileName = pattern.exec(text)[1];
```